# Java ArrayList get() as Integer rather than Object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

new to Java. Trying to understand the point of declaring my `ArrayList` as an `<Integer>`. I still have to cast my `.get()` result as an `int` in my methods for it to work, else it still returns an `Object`. eg: `(int) deliv.get(j)` int the Sort method's `for` loop.  Is there a way to avoid this or is my code the correct approach?  
 
Problem: Assume the array can change size, hence not just using primitive array. All numbers should be pairs, looking for the unique one missing it's pair value. I sort the array, then cycle through the pairs to look for a mismatch. Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
class StolenDrone{
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> deliv_id = new ArrayList<>();
    deliv_id.add(99);
    deliv_id.add(13);
    deliv_id.add(4);
    deliv_id.add(5);
    deliv_id.add(8);
    deliv_id.add(99);
    deliv_id.add(8);
    deliv_id.add(5);
    deliv_id.add(4);

    System.out.println("Array is: " + deliv_id);
    sort(deliv_id);
    System.out.println("Array is: " + deliv_id);
    int unique = findUnique(deliv_id);
    System.out.println("Unique ID is: " + unique);   
}

//Sort ArrayList into increasing order
static void sort(ArrayList deliv){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i<deliv.size();i++){
        for (int j=0; j<deliv.size()-1;j++){
            if((int) deliv.get(j)> (int) deliv.get(j+1)){
                temp = (int) deliv.get(j+1);
                deliv.set(j+1, deliv.get(j));
                deliv.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

//check pairs in ArrayList to find unique entry
static int findUnique(ArrayList deliv){
    for(int i = 0; i<deliv.size()-1;i+=2){
        if(deliv.get(i) == null){
            return -1; //no unique
        }
        if((int) deliv.get(i) != (int) deliv.get(i+1)){
            return (int) deliv.get(i);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

}
```

Comment: You are mixing up reference (aka object) types like Integer with primitive types like int. Using `ArrayList<Integer>` makes `get()` to return Integer; and as Integer and int is not the same, you need to "cast".

Comment: should be ArrayList<Integer> deliv_id = new ArrayList<Integer>(); then no need to cast. Use Collections.sort(deliv_id) to sort your array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static void sort(ArrayList deliv)`

Your method signature requests an untyped ArrayList.
The compiler cannot know what will be inside the ArrayList so it requires you to cast the result.

Change it to this:

`static void sort(ArrayList<Integer> deliv)`

Now the compiler knows it is an ArrayList of Integers.
So you wont need to add the cast to `get()`

Answer (score 4):

When you type parameterize `ArrayList<Integer>` the compiler knows that everything inside the ArrayList is of type `Integer` and will only allow you to add `Integers` to the list, and thus `get()` returns `Integer`. Without parameterizing the compiler will allow you to add any `Object` to the `ArrayList`, and thus calling `get()` will return an `Object` and requiring the cast to `int`.

To remove the need for casts you need to change parameters with type `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Integer>` in the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Integet is wrapper-class of int. You cannot set int as a type of ArrayList to work, but you can put there int type and it will be automatticly casted to Integer. To meke work it good you should do like this :

```
static void sort(ArrayList deliv){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i<deliv.size();i++){
        for (int j=0; j<deliv.size()-1;j++){
            if(deliv.get(j)> deliv.get(j+1)){ // You should not cast, Integer is Comparable
                temp = deliv.get(j+1).intValue();//Changes here
                deliv.set(j+1, deliv.get(j).intValue());//And here
                deliv.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: This was my original code before I started casting (int), but returns to the error of comparing two objects.As others have pointed out, including the <Integer> label on the ArrayList argument being brought into the method makes this code valid. Thanks.